# pip install requirements.txt not working properly

Tags: python, django, git, unix

I'm trying to install all my Python/Django packages on my Digital Ocean Django server. I have my `requirements.txt` in the root directory, so I perform `pip install -r requirements.txt` - however it doesn't work. Here's my `requirements.txt`:

```
amqp==2.2.2
billiard==3.5.0.3
celery==4.1.0
coverage==4.4.2
decorator==4.0.11
defusedxml==0.4.1
Django==1.11.8
django-allauth==0.29.0
django-apptemplates==1.2
django-celery-beat==1.0.1
django-common-helpers==0.9.1
django-cron==0.5.0
django-el-pagination==3.1.0
django-fs-trumbowyg==0.1.4
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-trumbowyg==1.0.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
get==0.0.0
imageio==2.1.2
kombu==4.1.0
markdown2==2.3.1
moviepy==0.2.3.2
numpy==1.13.3
oauthlib==2.0.1
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.0.0
post==0.0.0
public==0.0.0
python-magic==0.4.12
python3-openid==3.0.10
pytz==2017.3
query-string==0.0.0
request==0.0.0
requests==2.11.1
requests-oauthlib==0.7.0
schedule==0.4.3
setupfiles==0.0.0
tqdm==4.11.2
vine==1.1.4
```

here's the log:

```
Collecting amqp==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached amqp-2.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting billiard==3.5.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached billiard-3.5.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting celery==4.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached celery-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting coverage==4.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached coverage-4.4.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting decorator==4.0.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defusedxml==0.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached defusedxml-0.4.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Django==1.11.8 in ./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Collecting django-allauth==0.29.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached django-allauth-0.29.0.tar.gz
Collecting django-apptemplates==1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached django-apptemplates-1.2.tar.gz
Collecting django-celery-beat==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached django_celery_beat-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-common-helpers==0.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached django-common-helpers-0.9.1.tar.gz
Collecting django-cron==0.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached django-cron-0.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting django-el-pagination==3.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached django-el-pagination-3.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting django-fs-trumbowyg==0.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached django-fs-trumbowyg-0.1.4.tar.gz
Collecting django-markdown-deux==1.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached django-markdown-deux-1.0.5.zip
Requirement already satisfied: django-trumbowyg==1.0.3 in ./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
Collecting django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached django_widget_tweaks-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting get==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Using cached get-0.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 454, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/pip-build-9eo5rb8l/get/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9eo5rb8l/get/
```

I thought it was working and there was only an error with the `get==0.0.0` package - however when I perform `pip freeze` it shows:

```
Django==1.11.8
django-trumbowyg==1.0.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pytz==2017.3
```

which shows none of them worked. I installed `django-trumbowyg` manually with `pip install django-trumbowyg` which is why that is there, but the others are only there though setting up the Django server. So why does `pip install -r requirements.txt` not work and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looking at all your version `0.0.0` dependencies: they only contain a few lines of trivial code  and `setupfiles` seems to have been remove from pypi. Are you sure you need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be issues with the library sometimes.

Just edit the `requirements.txt.` and **remove the version number** in whichever package you are facing the problem.

```
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
get
imageio==2.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove `setupfiles` completely because `setupfiles` and `setupfiles==0.0.0` both gave an error. Do you know what this package does and what version i need? Tried looking but it seems to be a dead package.

Comment: @Zorgan, I don't think you need that package at any point in time. There is need of `setuptools` in some projects but not `setupfiles`. I don't know exactly what it does and how it got installed and came in `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

1. You should fix the package versions in your `requirements.txt`.
2. From the log, it shows pip is using the cached version of the modules from somewhere, you should probably try `--no-cache-dir` option.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install version ***0.0.0*** of ***get***

You should specify a correct version number in ***requirements.txt***.